# Python custom logging is not following the defined formatter style

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a custom logger configuration file defined in python (3.5), that is as follows:

```
# custom_logger.py
import logging
import socket
import logging.config
from xyz import LOG_LEVEL

class HostIdentifier(logging.Filter):
  """
  Get host identifier
  """
  def filter(self):
   return socket.gethostname()

# https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details
logging.config.dictConfig({
  "version": 1,
  "filters": {
    "host_name": {
      "()": HostIdentifier
    },
  },
  "disable_existing_loggers": False,
  "formatters": { 
    "standard": { 
      "format": "[%(asctime)s] _message_type=%(levelname)-8s _package_name=[%(name)-12s] _host_name=[%(host_name)s] %(message)s",
      "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"
    }
  },
  "handlers": { 
    "default": { 
      "level": LOG_LEVEL,
      "filters": ["host_name"],
      "formatter": "standard",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
    }
  }
})

logger = logging.getLogger("my-custom-log")


==============================

# main.py

from custom_logger import logger

logger.error("this is my error message")
```

I expected this logging should have printed - time, log level, package name, host name and then message as 
configured in this line `"format": "[%(asctime)s] _message_type=%(levelname)-8s _package_name=[%(name)-12s] _host_name=[%(host_name)s] %(message)s", "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"` in custom_logger.py

But it simply prints `this is my error message` what do I need to change in my config to get all elemnets spit out in the log?

Comment: Maybe need to specify when to use your `default` handler? Like `"root": { 'handlers': ['default'] }`?

Comment: No, that did not work. I however fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing it as follows:

```
class HostIdentifier(logging.Filter):
  """
  Get host identifier
  """
  def filter(self, record):
    record.host_name = socket.gethostname()
    return True

# https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details
logging.config.dictConfig({
  "version": 1,
  "filters": {
    "host_name": {
      "()": HostIdentifier
    },
  },
  "disable_existing_loggers": False,
  "formatters": { 
    "standard": { 
      "format": "[%(asctime)s] _message_type=%(levelname)-8s _package_name=[%(name)-12s] _host_name=[%(host_name)s] %(message)s",
      "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"
    }
  },
  "handlers": { 
    "default": { 
      "level": LOG_LEVEL,
      "filters": ["host_name"],
      "formatter": "standard",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
    }
  },
  "loggers": {
    "": { 
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "level": LOG_LEVEL,
      "propagate": True
    }
  } 
})
```